# String not getting passed in 'setText()' method in android?

Tags: android, string

The problem is in the setText() line. I get the string from the intent and it show by alone but not in the %s option. This is my code :

```
package com.example.roa.gimatryapp2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView resultText;
    private Button restartButton;
    private String mName;   //strinh name
    private int count;
    private ColorWheel mColorWheel = new ColorWheel();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        restartButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.restartButton);

        int color = mColorWheel.getColor();
        int color2 = mColorWheel.getColor();

        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
        restartButton.setBackgroundColor(color2);
        if(color == color2){
            restartButton.setBackgroundColor(color2);

        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mName = intent.getStringExtra("username");    //get the string from the intent
        count = intent.getIntExtra("result", count);


        resultText.setText("Hi %s , you have a grate name your name is equal to: ", mName + count);  //here is the problam. if it is like ("..." + mName)it show up

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: use `String.format` => `String.format ( "String" , args )`

Comment: read the doc and do tell what method you hope to call exactly and what effect do you want to achieve. Also please check that the intended effect is vaguely related to the description in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextView does not have a setText() method which reads in formatting args. You need to pass it a String (or other CharSequence) which has already been formatted. For your use case with a raw String, this would be something like

```
resultText.setText(String.format("Hi %s , you have a grate name your name is equal to: ", mName + count));
```

More often, you have a String defined in an xml resource instead, and you would use

```
resultText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.string_name, mName + count));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be use have used
`intent.putExtra("username");` in your previous `Avtivity` So here you have to get `String` in this `Activity`  something like this.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null) {
    mName = extras.getString("username");
}
```

Hope it Helps.